# Synchronize Control RGB LED remotely in real time swift

Tags: ios, led

I want the LED to change color as it is in the same led on and off. I save the color data to firebase and I want the led to change color. So i want to synchronize with ios app

Comment: Hello Berko... this question needs more detail for you to be able to get a useful answer.  Which LED are you talking about?  The flash on the back of the phone or some other LED device?

Comment: I'm talking about a led device. thanks @MichaelDautermann